# Anyone using Node.js with Amazon SNS and Apple Push Notifications?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I'm looking for examples of using node.js with Amazon SNS and Apple APN push notifications. We use Amazon for our hosting, and I have used SNS before, it's pretty simple. But the examples they have for push notifications are for java, and there is no examples for Node. It's confusing, as usual with them, and I'm hoping to cut my research and time spent short. It can't be that hard. I'm also wondering how they deal with errors, and the differences between the sandbox and production. Apple reacts differently between the two environments, not failing in the sandbox as they do in production.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It ends up not being that hard, just figuring out the documentation was unpleasant. You need to create the main endpoint for the SNS topic in the console, by far the easiest way, including the loading of the certificate. You then used createPlatformEnpoint to create an endpoint for each device id. That returns another SNS topic, specific fo that device, that you then use to send the message.

So, the following works to send a single message to a single client. If you want send something en masse, not sure you can do that. Also not sure how you deal with Apple's feedback, which you are supposed to check for failed sends.

```
config = require("./config.js").config;

var token = "1234567898123456789";

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: config.AWSAccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: config.AWSSecretKey});
AWS.config.update({region: config.AWSRegion});

var sns = new AWS.SNS();

var params = {'PlatformApplicationArn':config["AWSTargetARN"],'Token':token};

var message = 'Test';
var subject = 'Stuff';

sns.createPlatformEndpoint(params,function(err,EndPointResult)
{
    var client_arn = EndPointResult["EndpointArn"];

    sns.publish({
    TargetArn: client_arn,
    Message: message,
    Subject: subject},
        function(err,data){
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("Error sending a message "+err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Sent message: "+data.MessageId);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can we send any image along with message @cargomeister

Answer (score 8):

It's fairly straightforward as CargoMeister pointed out.

I've written a blog post about getting it setup check it out here http://evanshortiss.com/development/mobile/2014/02/22/sns-push-notifications-using-nodejs.html

I've also a Node.js wrapper module that is easier to use than the AWS SDK as I've worked around the documentation. It supports iOS and Android Push Services (as that's all I've tested/worked with), manages message formats other than Strings and exposes events: https://npmjs.org/package/sns-mobile

I haven't used topics to manage endpoints, not sure is that an issue though. You just create PlatformEndpoints first via the SNS console.

Comment: Nice. I'll check that out. One of the things that we have found out is that if you try to send a whole bunch all at once to new users, the end points have to be created, and it takes forever.

Comment: Yeah,I'd guess that's more so an I/O issue to do with how quickly Amazon can allow the creates to occur, and also the fact that creating each new user requires a new HTTP request

Comment: Your blog is not active @eshortie Could really use it right now :)

Comment: Updated link http://evanshortiss.com/development/mobile/2014/02/22/sns-push-notifications-using-nodejs.html

Answer (score 7):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
 IdentityPoolId: 'add IdentityPoolId'
});

AWS.config.region = 'add region';

var sns = new AWS.SNS();

   sns.createPlatformEndpoint({
    PlatformApplicationArn: 'add platform application arn',
    Token: 'add device token'
   }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
     console.log("errorMessage" + err.stack);
     return;
    }

    var endpointArn = data.EndpointArn;
    var payload = {
     default: 'Hello World',
     APNS: {
      aps: {
       alert: 'Hello World',
       sound: 'default',
       badge: 1
      }
     }
    };

    // first have to stringify the inner APNS object...
    payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);

    // then have to stringify the entire message payload
    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

    console.log('sending push');
    sns.publish({
     Message: payload,
     MessageStructure: 'json',
     TargetArn: endpointArn
    }, function (err, data) {
     if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
      return;
     }

     console.log('push sent');
     console.log(data);
    });
   });

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: A short summary would help reviewers (like me) to judge the validity of your answer; interested users wouldn't have to dive into the code to understand your approach. Just a sentence or two would be fine and not too much work.

Comment: This is the safest implementation I think.
Works for me. Thanks!