# AWS SNS push notification using Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I have searched AWS documentation and wasted couple of hours but could not find the API and code to send push notification using Node JS.
Can anybody help in sending AWS SNS push notification using Node JS on Android and iOS devices?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePushBaiduAPI.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609121/anyone-using-node-js-with-amazon-sns-and-apple-push-notifications

Answer (score 8):

Got the answer.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: '{AWS_KEY}',
  secretAccessKey: '{AWS_SECRET}',
  region: '{SNS_REGION}'
});

var sns = new AWS.SNS();

  var payload = {
    default: 'Hello World',
    APNS: {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Hello World',
        sound: 'default',
        badge: 1
      }
    }
  };

  // first have to stringify the inner APNS object...
  payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);
  // then have to stringify the entire message payload
  payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

  console.log('sending push');
  sns.publish({
    Message: payload,      // Required
    MessageStructure: 'json',
    TargetArn: {{TargetArn}} // Required
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
      return;
    }

    console.log('push sent');
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **sns-mobile**

The below example creates an SNS instance for an Android application identified by a PlatformApplicationArn

```
var SNS = require('sns-mobile'),


 EVENTS = SNS.EVENTS;

var SNS_KEY_ID = process.env['SNS_KEY_ID'],
  SNS_ACCESS_KEY = process.env['SNS_ACCESS_KEY'],
  ANDROID_ARN = process.env['SNS_ANDROID_ARN'];

var androidApp = new SNS({
  platform: SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.ANDROID,
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  apiVersion: '2010-03-31',
  accessKeyId: SNS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: SNS_KEY_ID,
  platformApplicationArn: ANDROID_ARN,
  //sandbox: true (This is required for targetting (iOS) APNS_SANDBOX only) 
});

// Add a user, the endpointArn is their unique id 
// endpointArn is required to send messages to the device 
androidApp.addUser('some_fake_deviceid_that_i_made_up', JSON.stringify({
  some: 'extra data'
}), function(err, endpointArn) {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }

  // Send a simple String or data to the client 
  androidApp.sendMessage(enpointArn, 'Hi There!', function(err, messageId) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }

    console.log('Message sent, ID was: ' + messageId);
  });
});
```

[For more detail see documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sns-mobile)